# Element type is invalid - React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Header was a component being used earlier, but now it no longer exists in the repo. Still it errors for header. There are no uses of Header throughout the project and not sure why it still errors to check for header.

I am aware such errors can be caused by issues when exporting - `default or const` and their respective imports using `{..}`, however I'm unsure why I'm getting this error for a component that I have deprecated the use for and the definition for the component itself no longer exists.

```
ERROR  Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `Header`.

This error is located at:
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AnimatedComponent)
    in AnimatedComponent
    in AnimatedComponentWrapper (created by Header)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by Header)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AnimatedComponent)
    in AnimatedComponent
    in AnimatedComponentWrapper (created by Header)
    in Header (created by HeaderSegment)
    in HeaderSegment (created by Header)
    in Header (created by HeaderContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by HeaderContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AnimatedComponent)
    in AnimatedComponent
    in AnimatedComponentWrapper (created by HeaderContainer)
    in HeaderContainer (created by CardContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by CardContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View
    in CardSheet (created by Card)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AnimatedComponent)
    in AnimatedComponent
    in AnimatedComponentWrapper (created by PanGestureHandler)
    in PanGestureHandler (created by PanGestureHandler)
    in PanGestureHandler (created by Card)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AnimatedComponent)
    in AnimatedComponent
    in AnimatedComponentWrapper (created by Card)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by Card)
    in Card (created by CardContainer)
    in CardContainer (created by CardStack)
    in RNSScreen (created by AnimatedComponent)
    in AnimatedComponent
    in AnimatedComponentWrapper (created by InnerScreen)
    in Suspender (created by Freeze)
    in Suspense (created by Freeze)
    in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
    in DelayedFreeze (created by InnerScreen)
    in InnerScreen (created by Screen)
    in Screen (created by MaybeScreen)
    in MaybeScreen (created by CardStack)
    in RNSScreenContainer (created by ScreenContainer)
    in ScreenContainer (created by MaybeScreenContainer)
    in MaybeScreenContainer (created by CardStack)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by Background)
    in Background (created by CardStack)
    in CardStack (created by HeaderShownContext)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by SafeAreaInsetsContext)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (created by StackView)
    in GestureHandlerRootView
    in GestureHandlerRootView (created by StackView)
    in StackView (created by StackNavigator)
    in Unknown (created by StackNavigator)
    in StackNavigator (created by ProfileOverview)
    in ProfileOverview (created by SceneView)
    in StaticContainer
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (created by SceneView)
    in SceneView (created by BottomTabView)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by Screen)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by Background)
    in Background (created by Screen)
    in Screen (created by BottomTabView)
    in RNSScreen (created by AnimatedComponent)
    in AnimatedComponent
    in AnimatedComponentWrapper (created by InnerScreen)
    in Suspender (created by Freeze)
    in Suspense (created by Freeze)
    in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
    in DelayedFreeze (created by InnerScreen)
    in InnerScreen (created by Screen)
    in Screen (created by MaybeScreen)
    in MaybeScreen (created by BottomTabView)
    in RNSScreenContainer (created by ScreenContainer)
    in ScreenContainer (created by MaybeScreenContainer)
    in MaybeScreenContainer (created by BottomTabView)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by SafeAreaInsetsContext)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (created by BottomTabView)
    in BottomTabView (created by BottomTabNavigator)
    in Unknown (created by BottomTabNavigator)
    in BottomTabNavigator (created by MainTabNavigator)
    in DataProvider (created by MainTabNavigator)
    in MainTabNavigator (created by AppLogic)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator
    in BaseNavigationContainer
    in ThemeProvider
    in NavigationContainerInner (created by AppLogic)
    in RNCSafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaProvider)
    in SafeAreaProvider (created by AppLogic)
    in AppLogic (created by App)
    in BLEProvider (created by App)
    in SensorProvider (created by App)
    in AuthProvider (created by App)
    in App
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
```

Initially, I tried to go through wherever it was being used and used the new implementation for NavHeader. However, that didn't fix the error. Next, I deleted the component itself and it still didn't fix anything.

Comment: If you are sure that you are no longer importing it or referencing the component, try to clear the cache. delete the app, kill the metro that is running in your terminal, run "npm start --reset-cache" and then "npm run android"

Comment: I tried that, for some reason it doesn't work. And I checked all files, nothing uses it